# Users History and Users saved database schema design

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I want to store into database the visited users and favourite users (when a user clicks on hearth icon). So, I could create 1 table, users_activities like so:

Users_activities:

- id_users (pk)
- id_users2 (pk)
- activity (varchar or enum, it'll contain "history", "favourite") (pk)
- created (datetime)

For the history.php or favourites.php pages, I'll select all, where id_users = X and activity = "history/favourite", join users table. For insert and update, I have a composite primary key, users, users2 and activity. If I'll find a users X, users2 Y and activity Z, update the row..else insert.

Otherwise, I could create 2 separated table, users_history and users_favourite, like so:

Users_history

- id_users (pk)
- id_users2 (pk)
- created

users_favourite

- id_users (pk)
- id_users2 (pk)
- created

it's a simple design and SQL is tiny simple than first form. Which is better? I use php and mysql.

Comment: I'd go with the second

Answer (score 1):

"History" sounds like a log of things.  "Favorites" sounds like a current set of values.  They have two different sets of usages and properties; do not put them in the same table.